# How to make status bar look like certain online ordering status bars in HTML/CSS/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a status bar that looks like this

[image]

but I would like it to look like this

[image]

This code I am using for the current one is below. My question is this: would it be easier to do this using a non clickable formatted radio button, which I have seen with a similar look, or to use a totally different approach? I think I can figure out how to change the colors based on what the current status is, but I don't know how to do the basic drawing of the shape.

```css
.container {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.progressbar {
  counter-reset: step;
}

.progressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 16.6666%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #7d7d7d;
}

.progressbar li:before {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #7d7d7d;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}

.progressbar li:after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #7d7d7d;
  top: 15px;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.progressbar li:first-child:after {
  content: none;
}

.progressbar li.active {
  color: green;
}

.progressbar li.active:before {
  border-color: #55b776;
}

.progressbar li.active + li:after {
  background-color: #55b776;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="progressbar">
    <li class="active">NOI Recieved</li>
    <li class="active">Request To Recieved</li>
    <li class="active">Recieved to Compelte</li>
    <li>Complete To Source</li>
    <li>Public Comment</li>
    <li>Branch Manager Issues</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could accomplish the basic shapes using a container with a border radius and overflow hidden, and [skewed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/skew()) [pseudo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) for the segments. Here's a quick proof-of-concept:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  padding: 1em 2em;
  position: relative;
}

li::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  transform: skew(-30deg);
  background: bisque;
  z-index: -1; /* behind the text */
}

li:first-child {
  /* extend the first item leftward to fill the rest of the space */
  margin-left: -4rem;
  padding-left: 4rem;
}

li:last-child {
  /* extend the last item rightward to fill the rest of the space */
  margin-right: -2rem;
  padding-right: 4rem;
}

.active::before {
  background: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li class="active">Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```